# Create route with a path like "about.domain.com" in React JS

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am using React JS and I would like to create a route with path `https://about.domain.com/`, the way it is with Facebook (https://about.facebook.com/). How do I do this?

This is what I currently have my path set to `/about-us`. Can I switch it to something like `.about/`?

```
<Route path="/about-us" component={AboutUs} />
```

Comment: No. `react-router-dom` only deals with the path portion of the URL, not the domain.

Comment: As Drew said, `react-router-dom` can't do it (and I don't know a package that can do it).
If you want to add subdomain, you need to create the DNS zones with your domain provider (Cloudlflare, OVH etc).
Once you did it, then I your React app, you can link to `https://about.domain.com/` with a basic redirection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this is not what you are trying to do. Most likely, you will want to do `domian.com/about-us` instead. But here we are in case you are curious.

`domain.com` or something similar is a domain name. You don't create it. You purchase it from domain name registrars. e.g. GoDaddy.

After you bought `domain.com`, then you can host a site on a subdomain `about.domain.com`. Note that this should be a separate site from what you are working on.

Then in your main application, which will be hosted on `domain.com` most likely, you create a hyperlink to `about.domain.com`.

Comment: So, 'about.domain.com' will be hosted separately then?

Comment: By design, yes. e.g. `facebook.com` and `about.facebook.com` are two separate web applications. If you are thinking of using `about.domain.com` instead of `domian.com/about-us` just for the sake of looking cool, then I highly recommend you don't do this. Facebook/Meta does that because `facebook.com` is linking to Meta's product (i.e. Facebook, the social media) itself. Logically, it doesn't make sense to add an `facebook.com/about` page there

Comment: Similarly, you see Google is using `about.google` as its about page. Because, `google.com` is reserved for Google Search, a product from Google. And it makes little sense to put a company about us page on `google.com/about`